# Matlab equivalent of Python's 'reduce' function

Tags: python, matlab, reduce, equivalent

I have a bunch of matrices of the same size m*n: `a, b, c, d`, and I'd like to find the maximum of them elementwise, like:

```
mx = max(a, max(b, max(c, d)));
```

apparently the code above is not concise enough, I've googled and didn't find much help about `max` on N matrices, or any matlab function like python's `reduce`. I haven't learned much about matlab, so is there one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a `n*m*4` matrix of your input, then you can use `max`:

```
M=cat(3,a,b,c,d)
max(M,[],3)
```

The `cat` with parameter `3` concatenates your matrices along the third dimension, and `max` finds the maximum along this dimension. To be compatible with arbitrary matrix dimensions:

```
d=ndims(a)
M=cat(d+1,a,b,c,d)
max(M,[],d+1)
```

Reduce itself does not exist, and typically you don't need it because multi dimensional inputs or varargin do the trick, but if you need it, it's simple to implement:

```
function r=reduce(f,varargin)
%example reduce(@max,2,3,4,5)
while numel(varargin)>1
    varargin{end-1}=f(varargin{end-1},varargin{end});
    varargin(end)=[];
end
r=varargin{1};
end
```